# Supervisord restart group when one process crashes/is killed

Tags: supervisord

I've seen a few older posts asking this but no responses. Hopefully someone who knows the solution can help

If a supervisord process group has one member goes down, is it possible to restart all of the members in that group?

Alternatively I could probably make an EventListener to restart the group, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution from supervisord.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a temporary solution, one can do the following

Add the following to your conf file:

```
; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
[rpcinterface:supervisor]
supervisor.rpcinterface_factory = supervisor.rpcinterface:make_main_rpcinterface

; Event listener, on any kid going down, restart all the children
[eventlistener:good_listener]
command=python /path/to/python_script.py
events=PROCESS_STATE
```

then the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from supervisor.childutils import listener
from subprocess import call

def write_stderr(s):
   sys.stderr.write(s)
   sys.stderr.flush()

def main():
   while 1:
      cmd_msg, cmd_body = listener.wait(sys.stdin, sys.

      if 'eventname' in cmd_msg:
         if cmd_msg['eventname'] == 'PROCESS_STATE_EXITED':
            write_stderr('Process has quit\n')
            call(["supervisorctl", "restart", "all"])

      listener.ok(sys.stdout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

This will do what you want, but it isn't the best way to do things (imo).